# 'Route with name 'something' does not exist' vue-router console.warn when using vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, router, vue-test-utils

I'm making test codes for vue.js component which uses vue-router using vue-test-utils.

Here are codes related to this.

```
const Routes = [{
  ...
 }, ...
 {
  ...,
  path: '/transfers',
  name: 'transfers',
  redirect: '/transfers/all',
  ...
 },...]
```

**Routes.ts**

```
export default class Transfers extends Vue {
  ...
  @Watch('$route', { immediate: true })
  async setDataResource (value: any) {
    const routeParams = value.params
    const paramKey: string = Object.keys(routeParams)[0]
    ...
  }
}
```

**Transfers.vue**

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from '../../router/Routes'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
...
const router = new VueRouter({ Routes })

...
describe('Elements', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.id = 'root'
  document.body.appendChild(div)

  router.push({ name: 'transfers', params: { processing: 'all' } })

  const wrapper = shallowMount(Transfers, {
    localVue,
    store,
    router,
    attachTo: '#root'
  })
  ...
})
```

**transfers.test.js**

What I wanna do is to test watch on $route with params.

It works well with 'params: { processing: 'all' }' but

```
console.warn
      [vue-router] Route with name 'transfers' does not exist
```

appears.

I can use router.push({ name: 'transfers' }) in .vue, so I think the name is registered to routes normally. But only for testing, 'Route with name 'transfers'' seems to not found.

The Routes.ts file originally didn't use name options for routes, but I added it since I can push params to router only using name option. I mean, name options are not necessary for our project!

So my question is,

- Is there any way to push params to router in test code, without using name option in route?
- If I should use name option, why does this warning only appears when testing?

Comment: try after wrapper declaration `wrapper.vm.$router.push({ name: 'transfers', params: { processing: 'all' } })`

Comment: `new VueRouter({ Routes })` should be `new VueRouter({ routes })` (and the import should also be named `routes`).

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Thank you for your answering! I tried with your suggestion `const wrapper = shallowMount(Transfers, {
    localVue,
    store,
    router,
    attachTo: '#root'
  })

  wrapper.vm.$router.push({ name: 'transfers', params: { processing: 'all' } })` but same warning occurs :(

Comment: @tony19 Thx! Thanks to your answer, I can push params with only path like `wrapper.vm.$router.push({ path: '/transfers/failed' })`. Are there any rules for us to use `routes` instead of `Routes`?

Comment: Yes. The `VueRouter` constructor expects `routes`, so that specific key must be used. Keys are case senstiive in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of testing in the last project I was working on. I always mocked my $route and $router (see snippet). I've created a Codepen (includes the whole file) of a page I was testing. It shows my basic setup and some ways I was testing the routing object. ie

```
let mocks = {
  $route: {
    path: '/some-path',
    query: {
      amount: null,
      loanType: null
    }
  },
  $router: [],
  $validator: {
    validateAll: jest.fn()
  },
  $toast: {
    show: jest.fn(),
    error: jest.fn()
  },
  $withProcessing: jest.fn()
}
```

It's a little hard to exactly diagnose your prob without jumping into the code but I hope you get something out of the below that helps you out.

https://codepen.io/RuNpiXelruN/pen/XWRKmoE

Comment: Thank you for your answering! I think I understood your suggestion and try it, but it failed... I make the `mocks = {
    $route: {
      path: '/transfers/all',
      params: { processing: 'all' }
    }
  }` and add it to wrapper `wrapper = shallowMount(Transfers, {
    localVue,
    store,
    mocks,` But when I console.log it in .vue`@Watch('$route', { immediate: true })
  async setDataResource (value: any) {
    console.log(value)` it returns _undefined..._